# Problem with my prompt in split screen terminal

Tags: bash, prompt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxmC.png)

I've been trying to make a better prompt for myself, but when i go on a split screen terminal it goes on a ramp like so.

Been fiddling with it for a bit but can't figure out why, anyone got an idea ?

```bash
last_cmd_ok_ko() {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 
    else
        echo 
    fi
}

PS1='╭─ $(last_cmd_ok_ko) \[\033[0;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\] \[\e[34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\033[0;92m\]\[\033[0m\]
╰─▶ \[$(tput sgr0)\]'
```

Here is my actual PS1 :

(The last_cmd_ok_ko is also out, keep printing a grey dot istead of the green or red one, but i kinda abandonned the idea of making it work properly...)

Comment: You need `\[` and `\]` around `$(last_cmd_ok_ko)`, just like all the escape sequences.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it didn't change a thing. For the last_cmd_ok_ko i'm guessing it's an encoding / font problem, but i haven't got around that kind of thing just yet :p

Comment: Probably best to ask at [unix.se]. If it only fails in split screen, it's something specific to your terminal emulator. Make sure you provide that detail when you post there.

Comment: its very tricky to make this kind of fancy thing work as expected. e.g. bash may even has no idea if  is 1-char wide or 2-char on screen. personally i'd not waste time on this.

Comment: Which terminal are you using ?

Comment: I'm on a bash terminal, but using the "screen" command to split